# How do build a nested route url with HTML.ActionLInk?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my route working correctly in the RouteConfig.cs

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "PendingListings",
      url: "PendingListings/{pl_id}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { pl_id = 1, controller = "Inspections", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

so I can type in:

http://localhost:3311/PendingListings/1/Inspections/Details/1

What I can't figure out is how to build the same URL with HTML.ActionLInk. I tried

`@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details","Inspections", new { pl_id = item.pending_listing_id, id = item.id })`

But that didn't give me what I want. I know it is because I do not under HTML.ActionLink so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `RouteLink` rather than `ActionLink` to call a specific route name, for example

```
@Html.RouteLink("Details", "PendingListings", new
{
  controller="Inspections",
  action = "Details",
  pl_id = 1,
  id = 1
})
```

will generate

> ..../PendingListings/1/Inspections/Details/1

[Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)